# Cannot read one column from parquet via pyspark while others are read correctly

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have some columns with string ids. One of them are read correctly, but another one cannot be red no matter what I do. I set limit(20), but it still has no result. My parquet file is quite big actually, but why I cannot read only one column and without it everything goes ok.

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)

pyspark --version
20/06/19 15:56:20 WARN Utils: Your hostname, anton-G5-5587 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.25 instead (on interface wlp0s20f3)
20/06/19 15:56:20 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/home/anton/Documents/libs/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.0.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.7
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2020-06-06T13:05:28Z
```

I use Spark prebuilt for Apache 3.2 and later

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.load("data/purchases.parquet")

df.select('client_id', 'product_id').limit(20).write.csv('c_id_to_p_id.csv')
```

And after I ran the code above, I got the following (full message is too long to post it)

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1115, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:46655)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 977, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1115, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

My parquet file schema looks like this

```
StructType( 
 List( 
  StructField(client_id,StringType,true),
  ...
  StructField(product_id,StringType,true),
  ...
))
```

Have anyone ever met the problem like this? Thank you for your help